# Why "Maybe.doOnDispose" is not supported in RxJava2?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm using [`Maybe`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html) class in RxJava2.

I registered the [`doOnDispose`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html#doOnDispose-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) callback to detect the Dispose event, but it is not fired.

```
Maybe.just("aaa")
    .doOnDispose({ /* do something */ })
    .subscribe( ... )
```

I looked at the RxJava 2 code, but `Maybe` seemed not to support `doOnDispose`.

`Maybe` is create `MaybePeek`(not `DoOnDisposeObserver`) object in `doOnDispose`,,,

```
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport("none")
public final Maybe<T> doOnDispose(Action onDispose) {
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new MaybePeek(this, Functions.emptyConsumer(), Functions.emptyConsumer(), Functions.emptyConsumer(), Functions.EMPTY_ACTION, Functions.EMPTY_ACTION, (Action)ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(onDispose, "onDispose is null")));
}

protected void subscribeActual(MaybeObserver<? super T> observer) {
    this.source.subscribe(new MaybePeek.MaybePeekObserver(observer, this));
}
```

But, `Single` is create `DoOnDisposeObserver`, and it is worked fine.

```
@CheckReturnValue
@SchedulerSupport("none")
public final Single<T> doOnDispose(Action onDispose) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(onDispose, "onDispose is null");
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new SingleDoOnDispose(this, onDispose));
}

protected void subscribeActual(SingleObserver<? super T> s) {
    this.source.subscribe(new SingleDoOnDispose.DoOnDisposeObserver(s, this.onDispose));
}
```

Why `Maybe.doOnDispose` is not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says about `doOnDispose(Action onDispose)`

> Calls the dispose Action if the downstream disposes the sequence.

Since your downstream never dispose it, it will never call.

```
Disposable disposable = Maybe.just("aaa")
    .doOnDispose({ /* do something */ })
    .subscribe( ... )

disposable.dispose();
```

Now the action in `doOnDispose` should be called.

Note that if the completion of the stream takes less time than the going to the next operation (`disposable.dispose()`), then the `onDispose` action should not be called. So, in order to verify it you can use a delay:

```
Disposable disposable = Maybe.just("aaa")
    .delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .doOnDispose({ /* do something */ })
    .subscribe( ... )

disposable.dispose();
```

Now the action should be fired.

Comment: It is amazing!  Thanks 